# Register CATEGORY_HOME intent on runtime

Tags: android-intent, broadcastreceiver, broadcast, intentfilter

I need to register (on runtime) custom BroadcastReceiver for intent filter that can be described in manifest as

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

and unregister receiver when user exits application by pressing some button in application (or
entering password).

Receiver registered using code

```
receiver_ = new MyReceiver();
filter_ = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
filter_.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
filter_.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
registerReceiver(receiver_, filter_);
```

doesn't receve intent, onReceive() function is not called.

What I'm doing wrong and is there any possibilities to solve this promlem?
Thanx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `BroadcastReceiver` only gets triggered by a broadcast `Intent` (ie: an `Intent` sent using `sendBroadcast()`). The Intent you are describing (ACTION=MAIN, CATEGORY=HOME) is not a broadcast `Intent`. That is an `Intent` that is used to start an Activity (ie: someone calls `startActivity()` with an `Intent` that looks like that).

It seems to me that you are trying to create a HOME-screen replacement. If that is what you want to do, you need to have an `Activity` with that `<intent-filter>` in your manifest. You can't register/unregister this dynamically.

If you need to enable/disable your HOME-Screen replacement, what might work (I haven't tried it, so I can't say for sure that it will work) is to enable/disable your HOME-Screen activity using the `PackageManager`. Have a look at `setComponentEnabledSetting()` here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html

Let us know what you find out!

Comment: Thank you David for expaining workflow of BroadcastReceiver. If it is possible to unregister intetn filter defined in manifets it solves the promblem! If I understood I can do it via setComponentEnabledSetting(). Thanx a lot, I'll try it.